# Trigger code for number

Tags: apex, trigger

here is a piece of code if the number is less than 9.00 Below code is working properly but if i want the  number between 9.00-5.00 i need to display same values in object__c then how to do that

```
if(trigger.new[0].Number__c <= 9.00 )
            {
                    object__c obj = new object__c();
                        obj .place__c = 'london';
                        obj .Score__c = 2;
                    insert obj ; 
            }
```

Comment: Not clear..!
What do u want to do if the number is between 9.00-5.00  ?

Comment: even if the no is between 9-5 place & score should save with same records

Comment: the trigger is on object__c right? and what are the events on the trigger?

Comment: Just add `&& trigger.new[0].Number__c >= 5.00` to your `if` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether the number is between 9.00-5.00 you can do like this

```
List<object__c > objList = new List<object__c >();
for(YourObject__c yourObj : trigger.new){
    if(yourObj.Number__c <= 4.00  && yourObj.Number__c >= 1.00){
        object__c obj = new object__c();
        obj .place__c = 'usa';
        obj .Score__c = 4;
        objList.add(yourObj);
    }
    else if(yourObj.Number__c <= 9.00  && yourObj.Number__c >= 5.00){
        object__c obj = new object__c();
        obj .place__c = 'london';
        obj .Score__c = 2;
        objList.add(yourObj);
    }
}
```

Please note the code that you posted was not bulkified and will not be able to handle bulk records.

Comment: Thank you, but in another case between 4.00-1.00 need to save record as place =  usa, score = 4 if between 5.00-9.00 need to save record as place =  london, score = 2. how to go with this

Comment: updated the answer to accommodate the same

Comment: thank you Avidev, I have a doubt regarding this code we mentioned if less than 9.00 place = london and score = 2, if it less than 4-1 than it doent mean that it is less than 9

Comment: But this is the way how if else works. If the first condition is satisfied then second condition will never be evaluated.Why dont you try out the code and check the same?